# jquery cycle with hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, cycle

hi all i need some help still very new to jquery

i am using the cycle add-on i have the following so far i am trying to find away of adding onto it a hover

so when a user hovers over the links in menu it is cycling through it pauses the cycle and switch to hover ie user control

but after awhile of mouse-out it resumes

```
var n=0
var dn=1
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow') 
.cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  500, 
timeout: 3000, 
before: function(curr, next, opts) {
     n=n+1;
    if (n>5) {n=1;dn=5}
    $('#item'+dn).removeClass("active");
    $('#item'+(n)).addClass("active");
    dn=n;
    } 
});

$(".slideshow").cycle('resume');

$(".slideshow").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).cycle('pause');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).cycle('resume');
});
});
```

any help on this would be great thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".slideshow").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout();
    $(this).cycle('pause');
}, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).cycle('resume');
    }, 500);
});
```

Current set to resume after 500ms of not hovering over the slideshow.

Comment: thank you but that just stops and resumes the show so close maybe i should explain better sorry i am trying to get it show the relevant slide and class with the hover event as well as pause

Comment: Oh so you want it to switch to the link which is hovered? I didn't understand your question, sorry! After it has switched to that image do you want it to resume cycling from that point or the previous point?

Comment: yes i want the hover to take over if the user wants to but once they mouseout for it to restart the cycle i hope that explains it better

Comment: thanks i already tried there not close to what i am trying to do but thanks for trying

Comment: Right. Hope you find whatever you're looking for!